Spring Batch: how to have FAST INSERT INTO TABLE 1 million messages from Kafka
I write you this message because I'm a bit lost because I'm not sure how to tackle my problem.
Context

SimpleJob(SingleThread) in Spring Batch that consumes 1 Million messages from a topic (internal trusted source) at 7 AM every the morning
and Inserts them (one by one) into an intermediate table (A)
Then reads rows from A by chunks of 1000 rows and inserts these rows (one by one) into the target table B

Technologies
JAVA 17, Spring Batch, MySQL
The problem
The job takes 23 hours to completes. I would it to reduce the time to less than 2 hours
Improvements suggestions

Removing the intermediate table: Would allow less SELECT/INSERT of 1 Million. I asked former developpers if there where reasons for maintaining this table (not used elsewhere).
USING BULK INSERT: I read this would help increase perfomance
Increase chunk Size (commit interval): chunk of 1000 seams too small and so more SELECT/INSERT. Chunk Size are necessary to avoid OutOfMemory Java Heap Space errors. But I don't know how to determine the good chunk size except testing values randomly

Questions

Do you see some good reasons of maintaining an intermediate table in that case ?
Do you know how should I proceed to determine the right chunk Size ?

Are there any standards in terms of values ?
Can I only try random values until it completes in an acceptable time ?


Do you think trying Partitioned job/ Multithreaded jobs could be helpful in my case ? Or would be overkill ?

Since all the threads would be writing to the same database (possible bottleneck ?)



Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

I see no need for the intermediate table. Try to ETL data from the queue to table B directly. You can try to use a multi-threaded step to speed up things.

Thanks a lot for your answer @MahmoudBenHassine ! OK I also would like to know : do you have any recommendations on how to determine the best chunk size ? OK, I'm also going to see how Multithreaded jobs work. I suppose that reading from Kafka could be faster with multiple threads. But do you think there could be no gain when writing to the database since all the threads would be blocked the database threads. Unless database also use multiple threads for writing into table. If you have any recommendations of documentation that would help on multi-threaded jobs working with Database. Thanks !

We can achieve bulk insert in to db performance by using following steps.

Use jdbcTemplate's batchUpdate() method by preparing the statements dynamically.

2.Utilise proper DB connection pool settings to optimize the db connections.
3.Decide on the chunk size based on DB server configuration.As most of the DB's (like Oracle/SQL server) will not support inserting more than 1000 records at a time.
4.Use multithreading approach to process the data with minimal time.
